# Cannot run konga docker in production mode

Tags: docker, kong, konga

I'm using this image `pantsel/konga` and deploy it to openshift but I get this error

```
error: Bootstrap encountered an error: (see below)
error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir './kongadata/uploads'
```

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM pantsel/konga
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV DB_ADAPTER=postgres
ENV DB_URI=postgresql://konga:konga@postgresql-kong.unicorn1.svc:5432/konga
ENV TOKEN_SECRET=some_secret_token

EXPOSE 1337
```

How can I fix that? Please help me

Comment: Did you true to run the docker dommand with `sudo` ?

Comment: @AbdullahAlHazmy `sudo command not found` if run with sudo

Comment: did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/pantsel/konga/issues/109),

> this is not a bug. You will just have to define the storage path
>   yourself to a directory Konga will have access permissions via the
>   env var `STORAGE_PATH` as you see in the logs

You can try with

```
FROM pantsel/konga
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV DB_ADAPTER=postgres
ENV STORAGE_PATH=$HOME/konga
```

Comment: I get this error `Fatal error: Unable to create directory ".tmp/public/styles" (Error code: EACCES).
Running "sass:dev" (sass) task`

Comment: did you rebuild docker image? its should not start with `.` it should start with `$HOME/konga`

Comment: yes I rebuild it. I make it work by comment line fs.makeDir in bootstrap config and disable grunt